# Migrating to CXF with Jaxb from xfire with agesi

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, xfire

I'm migrating my xfire soap project which uses aegis for databinding to cxf with jaxb. I got the new cxf project working for old xfire requests with aegis binding. But when i move the databinding to jaxb unmarshalling errror occurs.

This is my cxf web service definition.

```
   <!--<bean id="aegisBean" class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" scope="prototype"/> -->
   <bean id="jaxbBean" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean"
      scope="prototype">
    <property name="dataBinding" ref="jaxbBean"/>
    <property name="serviceConfigurations">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceConfiguration"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.XFireCompatibilityServiceConfiguration"/>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<jaxws:endpoint id="trace" address="/trace" implementor="#traceImplBean">
    <jaxws:serviceFactory>
        <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"/>
    </jaxws:serviceFactory>
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

I used @XMLRootElement Annotaion on my DTOs as following.

```
     @XmlRootElement(name = "context" )
     public class Context implements Serializable {
           private KeyValues keyValues;
             .....
      }


     @XmlRootElement(name = "keyValues" )
     public class KeyValues implements Serializable {
            private String tag;
            private String value;
            ....
     }
```

One method which i tested generated following soap request for cxf

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:pay="http://example.project.com"> 
        <soapenv:Header/>
          <soapenv:Body>
            <pay:trace>
               <pay:context>
                 <keyValues>
                    <tag>tag</tag>
                    <value>value</value>
                 </keyValues>
              </pay:context>
          </pay:trace>
         </soapenv:Body>
       </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**HOWEVER** old xfire generate following request, I have mark the difference.

```
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pay="http://example.project.com" xmlns:api="http://example.com">
         <soapenv:Header/>
             <soapenv:Body>
                <pay:trace>
                  <pay:context>
                     <api:keyValues>
                        ***<api:KeyValues>***
                          <api:tag>tag</api:tag>
                          <api:value>value</api:value>
                        ***</api:KeyValues>***
                     </api:keyValues>
                  </pay:context>
               </pay:trace>
           </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got following exception when i tried to send xfire request to cxf service.

```
  javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://example.project.com", local:"keyValues"). Expected elements are <{}keyValues>
```

So I think i need to add additional  tags to cxf request inorder to compatible with xfire. Does anyone knows how to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB, by default, uses unqualified elements whereas Aegis/XFire by default used qualified elements.   Couple ways around that:

1) For every element, specify the namespace.

@XmlElement(name = "tag", namespace = "http:...")

likely easier:

2) Add a package-info.java with:

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://......",
                                     elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

Comment: Thanks. That helps to resolve part of question. Now namespace is ok, but how can i generate wrapper element. @XMLElementWrapper can be used in fileds, but I have some methods that uses arrays as parameter. In these xfire soap request has wrapper which is not present in cxf request. see my question , i have marked the difference in old xfire request.